# how to auto generate the gatling simulation for rest api

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

i have an akka http scala project currently its UI is not ready yet but i have to do load testing using (https://gatling.io/)[gatling] for the routes after some researching i think i have to write the gatling simulation scala code manually, because we have the [recorder](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/recorder/) feature that records the simulation and generates test scala simulation code automatically so i want to know if there is some tool or plugin which auto generate the simulation for my routes right now i use postman for hitting my routes `(GET, POST, DELETE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recorder is really a proxy intercepting requests. While the default use case is intercepting them from the browser, there's no reason why you couldn't run the recorder and configure postman to point to it.

If you look at [the recorder documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/recorder/#listening-proxy-port) you can configure the listening port. (8000 by default)

In postman, there's a global proxy configuration section in 'Settings' - you need to configure the proxy server to be the ip of where you're running the recorder and the matching port.